# Block Broadcasting - Unsolicited Block Push

Tags: block, message, c++, block-header, broadcast

Can someone, please, direct me to the **source code section(s) relevant for an Unsolicited Block Push** as described in the [Bitcoin Developer Guide](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#term-unsolicited-block-push)?

I've been going through `main.cpp` and searched for the term *MSG_BLOCK*, serving as a beagle for finding the correct place in the code. 
But as I'm reading further, it seems to me as if a freshly mined block is not appended to a inventory message, with *MSG_BLOCK*, in order to send it as a "package" as response to a request [(GetData Response)](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#block) BUT is sent as a single message of this structure:

[image: image is a cropped version of en-ibd-block.svg from Bitcoin Developer Guide]

To me, up to now, the best canditate for *Unsolicited Block Push* seems to be [main.cpp#L2393](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L2393) part of `main.cpp` but I'm confused since I don't know if there is more of possibly relevant code (like [main.cpp#L3830](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L3830)) for *Unsolicited Block Push* in `/src/`.

***So:* In a first step, I'm looking for code that is relevant for broadcasting a newly found block. Can someone please help?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find all instances in the code where the client will send a `block` message by searching for `PushMessage("block"`. This is the only match:

```
void static ProcessGetData(CNode* pfrom)
{
[...]
    pfrom->PushMessage("block", block);
```

[(Source.)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3fce72eaa3ea75aa911e32c4d96313848338cede/src/main.cpp#L3830)

This means that the standard client only ever sends a block message when specifically asked for it. That incoming `getdata` message is probably triggered in turn by sending the remote node an `inv` message. (Though that's not necessary - you can ask for a block that the other node hasn't advertised.) This is the code that sends inventory messages:

```
//
// Message: inventory
//
vector<CInv> vInv;
vector<CInv> vInvWait;
{
    LOCK(pto->cs_inventory);
    vInv.reserve(pto->vInventoryToSend.size());
    vInvWait.reserve(pto->vInventoryToSend.size());
    BOOST_FOREACH(const CInv& inv, pto->vInventoryToSend)
    {
        // If the other node already knows the message, don't send
        if (pto->setInventoryKnown.count(inv))
            continue;

        // trickle out tx inv to protect privacy
        [...]

        // returns true if remote node hasn't seen it
        if (pto->setInventoryKnown.insert(inv).second)
        {
            // Add to the list of inventory messages to send
            vInv.push_back(inv);
            // If there's 1000 inventory messages queued up, send them
            // (Protocol limit is 50000 at a time.)
            if (vInv.size() >= 1000)
            {
                pto->PushMessage("inv", vInv);
                vInv.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    pto->vInventoryToSend = vInvWait;
}
// Send any that are left over.
if (!vInv.empty())
    pto->PushMessage("inv", vInv);
```

[(Source.)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3fce72eaa3ea75aa911e32c4d96313848338cede/src/main.cpp#L4973)

(pto represents the remote node in the above code.)

So the page you're looking at describes a behavior that you could implement, and that other clients will accept, but it doesn't describe the current core client behavior.

Comment: "describes a behavior that you could implement, and that other clients will accept, but it doesn't describe the current core client behavior."  I wrote the docs linked above, and I didn't realize that wasn't obvious.  Sorry.  It should be updated shortly: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.org/commit/b847610e1b129a85b3fd00c251b97864f2f89781

Comment: @DavidA.Harding That was fast. :)

Comment: @NickODell: Thanks, Nick! One thing is still not completely clear. You say: "_This means that the standard client only ever sends a block message when specifically asked for it. That incoming getdata message is probably triggered in turn by sending the remote node an inv message._" - does this mean: (1) node1 & node2 are both at _height n_ on a common active chain (2) node1 is faster and finds a _block n+1_ and pushes it to an inv message and sends this inv message to node2 and gets a getdata message from node2 asking for _block n+1_ (3) node1 sends a single block message with _block n+1_ ?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi Yes.

Comment: @NickODell: Ok but in what case will a **unsolicited** **single** block message be broadcasted to peers then??? Never? Is a freshly mined block sent unsolicitedly only inside an inv message?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi Never. Unless you modify your client.